# Save new User with number for id

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Do you know how can add a user with numeric id(example:1,2,3,4) and not with strings? I work in android studio and i add users dynamic by register activity
Check image 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use the add method, Firebase will use a generated document ID by Firebase instead of the custom id you provided.

To use a custom ID you need to use set instead of add

Checkout the offical document:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Answer (score 0):

What you have as keys in your JSON is the UID of the users. This is the idiomatic way to store user data in Firebase, so I would not recommend changing the keys to something else.

If you want Firebase Authentication to generate numeric UID values for its users, there is no way to configure that behavior for the existing providers. If this is a hard requirement for your use-case, you can [implement a custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) where you control what UIDs are generated.